# Using Type-Erasure to create runtime type_traits queries

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure

Is it at all possible to use Type Erasure to create objects that encapsulate an arbitrary type, (let's call it `ErasedType`), and can be queried at runtime to tell whether another arbitrary type `T` is convertible to `ErasedType`?

After thinking about it, I don't think it's possible - even though it seems it *could* potentially be possible in theory.  The compiler would know which types `T` we're trying to compare with `ErasedType`, and so could generate the necessary code before runtime.  The problem is that, in practice, there doesn't seem to be *ANY* way to pass a template parameter type from a Base class instance to a Subclass instance.

For example:

```
struct FooBase
{
    template <class TestType>
    bool is_convertible()
    {
        return call_derived();
    }

    protected:

    virtual bool call_derived() = 0;

    template <class ErasedType>
    void base_class_function() { }
};

template <class ErasedType>
struct Foo : public FooBase
{
    bool call_derived()
    {
        // Here we have access to the ErasedType but no access to TestType.
            //
        // We could pass ErasedType to a base class function by saying:
        //
        // this->base_class_function<ErasedType>();
        //
        // ...but that doesn't seem to help since we still don't have access to
        // TestType
    }
};
```

So, the goal is to be able to say something like:

```
FooBase* f = new Foo<int>();
bool res1 = f->is_convertible<double>(); // returns true
bool res2 = f->is_convertible<long>(); // returns true
bool res3 = f->is_convertible<std::string>(); // returns false
```

But, I can't see how the `FooBase::is_convertible` method could ever be implemented, since I see no way to make `TestType` and `ErasedType` accessible together, in the same function, so the compiler could compute the result of `std::is_convertible<TestType, ErasedType>::value`

So, is this at all possible?

Comment: Your type-erased base class is allowed to expose a virtual function that gives you the `type_id` of the concrete type... but traits are a compile-time construction that doesn't really interact with the dynamic typing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ... although you can build a lookup structure at runtime with that information... and query that at runtime. Another alternative would be faking double-dispatch on the type erasure to pass a 'convertible' checker... any of them require quite a bit of boilerplate code and would not be fully generic though.

Comment: @David, even with double dispatch, you still lose the template parameter whenever you call a polymorphic function, so how can you ever arrange a situation where `TestType` and `ErasedType` are BOTH non-hidden?

Comment: @Channel72: That is why I commented that you would need a good amount of *boilerplate*, the difference from the other approach is that you could implement the test on the erasure types... With enough time you could implement this in terms of type lists in a traits class. The *not fully generic* part of the comment is due to the fact that it would only pick the conversions defined by you in that list/lookup.

Comment: The (common) issue here is that you want a quadratic amount of data about types (given that you cannot access the compiler’s internal, linear amount of data about them) but the virtual/template mechanism is capable of generating only a linear amount (as can be seen by considering the case where each type argument is defined only in its own translation unit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed not possible in C++, *in general*. It takes quite a bit of meta-data to make arbitrary queries about types at runtime, and C++ tries to keep this minimal (sometimes to the point of being a bit annoying; a feature could be automatically opt-in "on use", so there's no unnecessary overhead, but I disgress).

As David has been alluding to, it's entirely possible to duplicate the compilers information up to a point, but never fully automatically. This limits the runtime type information to what you manually add.

Take a look at libraries like [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) that have an entire framework on top of C++ to provide this meta-data to see what kind of work is involved. Depending on the problem at hand, you may be able to get by without it.